# Remove objects from a list contained in a protobuf generated class

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

My protobuf object looks like this.

```
message Abc {
   repeated XYZ xyz;
}
```

When this gets converted to a class Abc, it has following methods for the `list<XYZ>`;

```
getXyzList(), getXyzBuilderList(), getXyzOrBuilderList()
```

Lets say this list contains 4 objects of class `XYZ`, and I iterate over this list. Based on a condition I need to remove specific objects from this list.

Since while iterating over the list I can't remove the objects, I add the objects into another list e.g. say `tempList` (of type `List<XYZ>`).

Now lets assume that `tempList` has 2 objects from the list. What is the best way to remove these 2 objects from the original list?

I can't do `Abc.getXyzList()` or `Abc.getXyzOrBuilderList()` since it is immutable. If I do `Abc.getXyzBuilderList()`, it changes the object references (keeping contents same).

If I do `Abc.getXyzBuilderList().removeAll(tempList)`, the object references from `tempList` and  `Abc.getXyzBuilderList()` are different so the objects are not removed.

How can I get around this problem?